# Better way to render a work schedule with Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Here is how I do it now:

```
<p><strong>@lang('date.monday')</strong>    <span>{{ $profile->getSchedule()[\Carbon\Carbon::MONDAY]['from'] }}:00 - {{ $profile->getSchedule()[\Carbon\Carbon::MONDAY]['to'] }}:00</span></p>
<p><strong>@lang('date.tuesday')</strong>   <span>{{ $profile->getSchedule()[\Carbon\Carbon::TUESDAY]['from'] }}:00 - {{ $profile->getSchedule()[\Carbon\Carbon::TUESDAY]['to'] }}:00</span></p>
<p><strong>@lang('date.wednesday')</strong> <span>{{ $profile->getSchedule()[\Carbon\Carbon::WEDNESDAY]['from'] }}:00 - {{ $profile->getSchedule()[\Carbon\Carbon::WEDNESDAY]['to'] }}:00</span></p>
<p><strong>@lang('date.thursday')</strong>  <span>{{ $profile->getSchedule()[\Carbon\Carbon::THURSDAY]['from'] }}:00 - {{ $profile->getSchedule()[\Carbon\Carbon::THURSDAY]['to'] }}:00</span></p>
<p><strong>@lang('date.friday')</strong>    <span>{{ $profile->getSchedule()[\Carbon\Carbon::FRIDAY]['from'] }}:00 - {{ $profile->getSchedule()[\Carbon\Carbon::FRIDAY]['to'] }}:00</span></p>
<p><strong>@lang('date.saturday')</strong>  <span>{{ $profile->getSchedule()[\Carbon\Carbon::SATURDAY]['from'] }}:00 - {{ $profile->getSchedule()[\Carbon\Carbon::SATURDAY]['to'] }}:00</span></p>
<p><strong>@lang('date.sunday')</strong>    <span>{{ $profile->getSchedule()[\Carbon\Carbon::SUNDAY]['from'] }}:00 - {{ $profile->getSchedule()[\Carbon\Carbon::SUNDAY]['to'] }}:00</span></p>
```

The schedule stored as JSON and casts to array, i.e. `$profile->getSchedule()` returns this structure as an array. 
Example:

```
{
  "0" : {
    "from" : "05",
    "to" : "15"
  },
  "1" : {
    "from" : "14",
    "to" : "08"
  },
  "2" : {
    "from" : "10",
    "to" : "04"
  },
  "3" : {
    "from" : "11",
    "to" : "00"
  },
  "4" : {
    "from" : "21",
    "to" : "19"
  },
  "5" : {
    "from" : "02",
    "to" : "20"
  },
  "6" : {
    "from" : "13",
    "to" : "20"
  }
}
```

If you can also come up with better schedule storing options (to simplify rendering), I will be glad to hear them.

Comment: It's hard to suggest better alternatives without knowing the current data format etc.

Comment: @marty Data format of what exactly?

Comment: What does `$profile->getSchedule()` return for a start?

Comment: @Marty, I've updated the question

Comment: Is there the option to change `from` and `to` to proper dates (e.g. `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`) so the day (Monday, etc) can be derived from that? Then you can just do a `for` to spit everything out.

Comment: @Marty, yes it's a work in progress, but it doesn't make sense for me to store this as proper dates, because I don't need them. I only interested to store working hours for each day of week.

Comment: Even if you changed it something like `{ "YYYY-MM-DD": { "from": "HH", "to": "HH" } }` that would give you what you need to simplify and also make the data a little more valuable than numbers you have to map to what I assume are constants for each of the days of the week.

Comment: I agree that it would simplify rendering, but using full date like `"YYYY-MM-DD"` to identify a day of week is at least misleading I think.

Answer (score 0):

You should just handle all of this logic in your controller. In your controller, run `$profile->getSchedule()` one time, then do the Carbon parsing and send `$schedule` to your view.

`$schedule` could look like

```
[
  Monday:{
    open:'08:00',
    close: '22:00'
  }
  ...
];
```

Then in blade you're just doing:

```
@foreach($schedule as $day => $hours)

  <p><strong>{{$day}}</strong>
  <span>{{ $hours['open'] }} - {{ $hours['close'] }}</span></p>

@endforeach
```